# How to knife bootstrap ec2 private instances using NAT gateway

Tags: amazon-ec2, bootstrap-4, chef-infra, knife

I am trying to bootstrap my private IP instance with its NAT Gateway using below command, but unable to bootstrap.

```sh
$knife bootstrap x.x.x.x --ssh-gateway x.x.x.x --ssh-user ec2-user --sudo --ssh-identity-file mypemfile.pem -N <nodename>
...

ERROR: Train::Transports::SSHFailed: SSH command failed (command timed out: ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o BatchMode=yes -o LogLevel=ERROR -o ForwardAgent=no -i mypemfile.pem root@x.x.x.x -p 22 -W x.x.x.x:22)
```

Comment: to understand whether it is chef or ssh related, please run the ssh command in your output with `-vvv` for verbose output. if there is no error with the ssh, try running knife with `--log_format debug` to get a verbose output.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but '-vvv' showing Chef Client version and '--log_format debug' is not working.

Comment: Probably, you didn't allow access to 22 port on your instance. In AWS all ports are closed by default, check out your security group.

Comment: @ManishBadgujar: sorry for that, it should be `--log_level` and not `--log_format`. please visit chef documentation and ssh for getting the verbose output